# What's the difference between Dataflow sql, Beam SQL (Zeta sql or CALCITE SQL)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, beam-sql

While browsing I just came across Dataflow SQL. Is it any different from beamSQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Apache Beam SQL` is a functionality of `Apache Beam` that allows you to execute queries directly from your pipeline.

As you can see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/overview/), `Beam SQL` has two options of `SQL` syntax: [Beam Calcite SQL](https://calcite.apache.org/) and [Zeta SQL](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/zetasql/overview/). The advantage of using `Zeta SQL` is that its very similar to `BigQuery`'s syntax hence its useful in pipelines that read from or write to `BigQuery`.

`Dataflow SQL` is a functionality of `Dataflow` that allows you to create pipelines directly from a `BigQuery` query. It's said in the documentation that it supports the `Zeta SQL` syntax (BigQuery syntax).

To create a new `Dataflow` job through the `BigQuery`'s console, to the following steps:

1. Go to BigQuery's console
2. Just under the Query editor, click in **More** and then in **Query settings**
3. Select **Cloud Dataflow engine** in the first option as you can see below

[image]

After that, you can click in **Create Cloud Dataflow job** and your query will become a job in `Dataflow`.

I hope it helps

Comment: What is a use case for using Dataflow SQL when there is BigQuery SQL..What would be more cost effective? I am not exploring using BigQuery Flexslots to save on costs of query.